# Open source Yahoo! Answers implementation?

Tags: open-source

Do you know some open source implementations of [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/)?

Preferably in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither open source, nor PHP, but you might be interested in [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com).